# How can i linked CLR project library to windows service?

Tags: c++, windows, service, clr, native

I have one native project which is written C++. I make one another CLR project which make wrapper for native project.

but I don't know how I linked CLR project library to windows service project.

Comment: I think you will need to clarify your question. As best as I understand your question, you just need to know how to interact (for example call the service and get something back) with a service. When you say "CLR project" do you mean C++/CLI? Please provide more clarification of other parts too.

Comment: yes C++/CLI library which I want to linked with the windows service project...

actually I have created c++ code .I want to windows service.. so I c++/cli through I converted and make dll library but I am facing project in visual studio there is no option to link with that library

Comment: Can you update your question to further explain the project that you are accessing the service from and what you need the service to do for it? Some more information will help.